# How to link email address too Google Form answer?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am currently attempting to send a Google Form to various users.

How would I go about with making their email attached to the form (when I see the response, I see the email address of the responder)? Is there any way to do this with Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution although it is not code related:

It is possible to share pre-filled links as follow: `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/../viewform?entry.1640447617=myemail@gmail.com`

And possible to concatenate to replace and concatenate `viewform?entry.1640447617=myemail@gmail.com`